# Append array of object values if index is the same index of a div list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop

I need help: I have one object with multiple array inside; i need to cycle all my array values and then append this values inside my HTML div list (with the same class).
object[0] with div[0];  object[1] with div[1] ecc...

This is an example:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<body>
    
    <div class="appendDiv">
        <h1>First</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="appendDiv">
        <h1>Second</h1>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
⁄⁄JS

var values = [
    {
        'name': "john"
    },
    {
        'name': "doe"
    }
]

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    value = values[i];
    var name = value.name;
    
    $('.appendDiv').each(function(index, val){
        if (i === index) {
            $('.appendDiv').append('<p>' + name + '</p>');
        }
    })
}
```

But this method return to me with a wrong result like this:

**First**
**John**
**Doe**

**Second**
**John**
**Doe**

I need a result like this:

**First** (my first .appendDiv [0])
**John** (my first array name value [0])

**Second** (my second .appendDiv [1])
**Doe** (my second array name value [1])

Thank you.

Comment: `$('.appendDiv').append('<p>' + name + '</p>');` <= So look at this line, and think about this line outside of the context of how your logic is trying to use it.  What does this logic actually do?

Comment: Secondly, why do you need to look up the divs again?  You are looping over them already

Comment: Yes @jdlm, and for you which is the best solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need 1 for each loop on your `Div`. You can uses the index to see if the corresponding array contains a value.

If you're comparing with index, then the code should have an if statement to check data exists (to prevent possible null exceptions).

```
var values = [
    {
        'name': "john"
    },
    {
        'name': "doe"
    }
]

$('.appendDiv').each(function (index) {
    var value = values[index];
    if (value && value.name) {
        $(this).append('<p>' + value.name + '</p>');
    }
});
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="appendDiv">
    <h1>First</h1>
    <p>john</p>
</div>
<div class="appendDiv">
    <h1>Second</h1>
    <p>doe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Greg! This is the right solution for me; thanks for the code and info about that.